# Android Studio Instant Run: Slice Assets?

Tags: android-studio, android-instant-run

Android Studio Instant Run will only install the slices of changed code to a device when you debug to save time. However, it seems not to slice the assets directory. Unfortunately, our app has a lot of assets files. Even if we only changed one assets file, all the assets files will need to be installed again since they are all in one slice(the APK file actually). Which makes the Instant Run meaningless for our app.

Is there a way we can only install changed assets files when running an app in Android Studio? Like how Xcode handle it.